# trouble understanding thevenin equivalent

Tags: bjt, thevenin, common-emitter

[image]
I really don't understand how the middle ciruit is the thevenin equivalent of the left-most circuit, any help?

Comment: A & B are identical schematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I really don't understand how the middle circuit is the Thevenin equivalent of the left-most circuit, any help?*

The middle circuit is an intermediate step in moving from the left-most circuit to the Thevenin equivalent on the right.

In the middle circuit, Vcc is split into two identical parts; one that powers the collector via Rc and one that powers the base via R1. The middle circuit allows you to more easily "see" how the right-most circuit is created.

I'll draw a red connection on the middle diagram like this: -

[image]

Do you see how that red connection is not needed and why you can duplicate voltage sources where applicable?

Answer (score 1):

A & B are identical schematics, while C is the Thev. Reduction in V and R to be equivalent and identical response of source impedance and voltage and effects of loading from hFE*Re on base V.